# Neo4j K-means algorithm

Tags: neo4j, k-means

Hello Stack Overflow community,
I'm really need a help about something,
I want to apply a community detection algorithm on a graph, contains distances between person ( social network)
I want to know if neo4j k-means algorithm of community détection works with this type of graphs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The k-means for Graph Data Science (GDS) is in alpha mode, meaning on the early stage  of development and can have major change(s) on it.

Here is the documentation: https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/alpha/kmeans/

Enjoy reading it!

Comment: jose_bacoy, thank you so much for this answer, but there is an algorithm for community detection that can interprate weights as distances ?, i see for Louvain but it can't